# Java unicode characters error in cmd

Tags: java, unicode, printing, cmd

I have the following class in Java which prints "Hello World" in portuguese:

```
public class PrintUnicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Olá Mundo!");
    }
}
```

I am using Eclipse, so I exported the project to a Runnable Jar File. After that, I went to cmd (Windows 7) and ran the generated jar file.

The result was:

```
Olß Mundo!
```

Is there an easy way to avoid this error?

Comment: In Eclipse you can set the encoding of the Java source code. If you don't do this the compiler assumes a default encoding and text may come out wrong.

Comment: I believe this it not the reason. Even if you change the file encoding, the error persists. It is a Java problem when handling unicode chars with System.out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. Just change to:

```
public class PrintUnicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.console().printf("Olá Mundo!");
    }
}
```

The error with System.out happens because:

> By default, Java encodes Strings sent
>   to System.out in the default code
>   page. On Windows XP, this means a
>   lossy conversion to an "ANSI" code
>   page. This is unfortunate, because the
>   Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) can
>   read and write Unicode characters. ([source here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/java-unicode-on-windows-command-line.html))

Comment: I've workarounded this problem before by encoding manually: `System.out.write(myStr.getBytes(consoleCharset));` but this is far better.